# JenkinsのSubversion Plug-inを使用したSCMポーリングが"svn: E175002: unknown host"とエラーになる

Tags: jenkins, svn

## 概要

Windows10 Home上に建てたJenkinsにSubversion Plug-inを導入し、SCMポーリングでコミットを検知してビルドを開始するジョブを作成しました。

最初の1回目のsvn checkoutは問題なく成功するのですが、2回目以降のポーリングで `org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: unknown host`とエラーが発生し、svn updateができません。

原因や対策方法についてご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけると幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

## 詳細

最初の実行でビルドマシン上にチェックアウトされたリポジトリをTortoiseSVNのリポジトリブラウザで開いた所、正常に閲覧することができたので、リポジトリURLが間違っているという事もないと思います。

詳細なログは下記に貼っていますが、ログ中に`Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy_server`と出ているのですが、マシンにもJenkinsにもProxyの設定は行っていません。

SVNサーバーも[Backlog](https://backlog.com/ja/)のものを利用しているので、Proxyが必要という事もありません。

### これまで試したこと

- JVMのDNSキャッシュの問題かと思い、ビルドマシンにて `%JAVA_HOME%\conf\security\java.security`を編集して`networkaddress.cache.ttl=0`を設定しマシンを再起動しましたが、解決できませんでした。
- 他プロジェクトでは問題なくSCMポーリングできているので、Subversion Plug-inのバージョンを同じもの(2.15.1)に合わせてみましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。（現在は最新の2.15.5に戻しています）

### 環境、バージョン、Jenkinsの設定など

#### 環境

- Jenkinsマシン(master): Windows10 Home
- ビルドマシン(slave): Windows10 Home

  - `Launch agent by connectiong it to the controller`でスレーブノードとして接続

#### バージョン

- Windows10 Home 21H2
- OpenJDK 11.0.2
- Jenkins 2.332.3
- Subversion Plug-in 2.15.5

#### Jenkinsの設定

- Jenkinsの「システムの設定」内の「Subversion」の「ワークスペースバージョン」は`1.8`を指定しています。

  - もう一つの設定項目の「対象外リビジョン属性名」については空欄のままです。
  - BacklogのSVNサーバーのバージョンは`1.8`が利用されているようです。[※](https://support-ja.backlog.com/hc/ja/articles/360036150013-Subversion%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B-)
- Jenkinsのジョブのソースコード管理で`Subversion`を選択し、2つのモジュール（リポジトリURL）を指定しています。

  - 2つのリポジトリのCredentialsにBacklogのID・PWを正しく指定していますが、`Unable to access the repository`と警告が出ています
  - 警告を無視して実行した所、問題なく`svn checkout`できていますが、`svn update`ができない状況です

### ログ

#### ジョブ「MyProject_Build_Trigger」の「Subversionのポーリングログ」

```
Started on 2022/06/15 15:32:00
Received SCM poll call on master for MyProject_Build_Trigger on 2022/06/15 15:32:02
ERROR: Failed to check repository revision for https://my-company.backlog.jp/svn/MY_PROJECT_1/repos/directory/sub-directory
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: unknown host
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/MY_PROJECT_1/repos/directory/sub-directory'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:112)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:96)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:765)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:340)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:910)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:702)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:113)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1047)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:169)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:119)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:180)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:43)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:47)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:31)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doInfo(SVNWCClient.java:2535)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.parseSvnInfo(SubversionSCM.java:1311)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.checkInternal(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:115)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.call(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:78)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.call(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:27)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:47)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(SubversionSCM.java:1508)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(SCM.java:419)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.poll(SCM.java:436)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject._poll(AbstractProject.java:1394)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.poll(AbstractProject.java:1300)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.runPolling(SCMTrigger.java:616)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.run(SCMTrigger.java:663)
    at hudson.util.SequentialExecutionQueue$QueueEntry.run(SequentialExecutionQueue.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy_server
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:796)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1504)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1297)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1247)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createAddres(SVNSocketFactory.java:207)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createPlainSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:68)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:132)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:415)
    ... 34 more
ERROR: Failed to check repository revision for https://my-company.backlog.jp/svn/MY_PROJECT_2/repos/directory/sub-directory
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: unknown host
svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/MY_PROJECT_2/repos/directory/sub-directory'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:112)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:96)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:765)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:340)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:910)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:702)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:113)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1047)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:169)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:119)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:180)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:43)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:47)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:31)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:21)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1239)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNWCClient.doInfo(SVNWCClient.java:2535)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.parseSvnInfo(SubversionSCM.java:1311)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.checkInternal(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:115)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.call(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:78)
    at hudson.scm.CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.call(CompareAgainstBaselineCallable.java:27)
    at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:47)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(SubversionSCM.java:1508)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.compareRemoteRevisionWith(SCM.java:419)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.poll(SCM.java:436)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject._poll(AbstractProject.java:1394)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.poll(AbstractProject.java:1300)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.runPolling(SCMTrigger.java:616)
    at hudson.triggers.SCMTrigger$Runner.run(SCMTrigger.java:663)
    at hudson.util.SequentialExecutionQueue$QueueEntry.run(SequentialExecutionQueue.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: proxy_server
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:796)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1504)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1363)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1297)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1247)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createAddres(SVNSocketFactory.java:207)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createPlainSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:68)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:132)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:415)
    ... 34 more
Done. Took 2.2 秒
No changes
```